# Rock, Paper, Scissors with Bots

Tags: story-identification

This was a science fiction game that I would have bought (and my mother has since thrown away) sometime in the late seventies or possibly early eighties. I believe it came in a bag (there were a series of games like that back then, I don't know if they still exist). The basic game concept was that you were at war, and your 'soldiers' were all of these little bots. Each bot had a concept (slow moving and heavy, could jump, could fly, etc.) but they also did a kind of rock-paper-scissors thing: Bot A was good at killing Bot B, Bot B could trash Bot C; and Bot C could eat Bot A for lunch... etc.
The idea was you had these factories turning out these bots and you had to manage the right kind of production to kill your enemies, make new factories, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like "Rivets", one of Metagaming's Microgames.

They indeed came in a bag, the manual was like 4x6 inches.

I remember playing Rivets but not too many details.

There is a cover pic [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2192/rivets)

[image]

As well as more info:

> Rivets is a tactical level science fiction game of robotical warfare in the 22nd century. The players choose their robot armies, program them, and maneuver them to destroy the computer complex that controls the enemy's robots.
>
> Game components include this rulebook, an 8 1/4" by 14' game map, and 118 counters"

Comment: Wow, you're awesome. I remember the game 'GEV' that I bought from them too. Wish I still had them all :)

Comment: They were really great. Ogre was my fav and then Warpwar. I've still got them, I would have scanned the cover but I'm out of town.

Comment: Did you ever hear the story about GEV? As I heard it they designed a sci-fi heavy tank game, and also had GEV's in it. However the GEV's stole the show, as their movement rules (they were very fast) allowed them to dart in, fire, and leave before the tanks could shoot at them. Thus the game became 'GEV' :)

Comment: It didn't really *become* GEV; GEV was a sequel/expansion to Ogre, which is still around. GEVs were very good at hit-and-run, but light on firepower and armour, and it was often possible to catch them with unfriendly terrain.